# How to extract best accuracy and other details once the fit.generator gives results

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

My code is working properly. I have used Save_Best_only function and Keras fit.generator to train the model. It gives the values. I need to extract the best accuracy, best validation accuracy among the epochs and print them in a new cell on jupyter notebook.

I assigned a variable for fit generator and try to get the details. But I don't know the keywords to print.

```py
Test_Model = model_final.fit_generator(
train_generator,
epochs = 2,
#steps_per_epoch = 8,
validation_data = validation_generator,
#validation_steps = 8,
callbacks = [es,cp]
)

print (Test_Model)
```

Best Accuracy is `99.2%` & Best Validation Accuracy is `99.8%` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Fixed**

Managed to get the confident accuracy & validation accuracy using `.history` from the `fit_generator` dictionary and passed values into separate arrays as follows:

```
con_acc = Test_Model.history['acc']
val_acc = Test_Model.history['val_acc']
```

Then, get the max value of each array using `max` function in Python as follows:

```
max(con_acc)
max(val_acc)
```